# Take 2 dimensional list from user input

Tags: python

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
n = int(raw_input())

a = [[0]*n]*n

for i in xrange(0,n):
    s = raw_input()
    for j in xrange(0,n):
        a[i][j] = int(s[j])

print a
```

I am new to python. While taking user input from stdin, I gave the following values in stdin

> 3
>
> 101
>
> 010
>
> 101

But when I print, the output comes as

```
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Whereas the output should be

```
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Can someone please guide me what am I missing?

I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Change `a` to this :

```
a = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

Because `[[0]*n]*n` will create a single instance each time, so it will take the last assigned value to all instances because they are same referring to.They're all the same exact list in memory. When you use the `[[0]*n]*n` syntax, what you get is a list of n many [0] objects, but they're all references to the same object. They're not distinct instances, rather, just n references to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problematic line:

```
a = [[0]*n]*n
```

This, counterintuitively, creates only a single instance of `[0, 0, 0]` and makes three references to it. That means it is overwritten by your last input each time.

You can solve it by instead writing:

```
a = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: It works. But can you explain what is the difference between what I did and your code snippet. Or can you point me to a article explaining the same.

Comment: Like me and the other answer said - the python syntax `[<something>]*n` creates a list with `n` copies(references) of something. Since the something in this case is a list (`L = [0]*3  = [0, 0, 0]`), the result would be `[L, L, L]` where they are *all references to the same list L*.

The code I used solved this problem using list comprehension - it created a new list each time. You could also write it this way: `a = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]` which is shorter but is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

First you define matrix with full range like

```
a = [[0 for i in range(n] for i in range(n)] 
a[i][j] = any value
```

I hope it's work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Obviously you would need to add a lot of checks.

```
n_rows = int(raw_input('Enter Number of rows required: '))
n_cols = int(raw_input('Enter Number of cols required: '))

rows = []
for i in range(0, n_rows):
    row = int()

final_list = []
for i in xrange(0, n_rows):
    s = list(raw_input('Enter the values for row no. {} (Separated by commas): '.format(i+1)))
    s_list = [int(i) for i in s if i != ',']
    if len(s_list) != n_cols:
        raise ValueError('Number of values entered are not correct')
    else:
        final_list.append(s_list)

print final_list
```

Or you can also try the [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) Module